# Pop multiple fragments from stack

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am writing an application with Xamarin.Android and MvvmCross, but this question applies for native Android in general. I want to be able to declare a root fragment, so that I can later pop off all fragments on top of it on the stack. For example, if I have the fragments:

A|B|C|D

And I am currently on fragment D, I want to be able to pop off fragments B, C and D instantly to get back to fragment A. I am trying to do this with the `CurrentFragmentManager.PopBackStack` method in my view presenter, but it's not working as I expect it to. Here is my implementation:

```
public class ViewPresenter : MvxAppCompatViewPresenter
{
    private int _rootFragmentId;
    private int _currentFragmentId;

    public ViewPresenter(IEnumerable<Assembly> androidViewAssemblies) : base(androidViewAssemblies)
    {
        AddPresentationHintHandler<SetRootHint>(SetRootHintHandler);
        AddPresentationHintHandler<PopToRootHint>(PopToRootHintHandler);
    }

    protected override void ShowFragment(Type view, MvxFragmentPresentationAttribute attribute, MvxViewModelRequest request)
    {
        base.ShowFragment(view, attribute, request);

        // Keep track of the ID of the current fragment (the ID that is given in the Resource)
        _currentFragmentId = attribute.FragmentContentId;
    }

    private bool SetRootHintHandler(SetRootHint hint)
    {
        _rootFragmentId = _currentFragmentId;

        return true;
    }

    private bool PopToRootHintHandler(PopToRootHint hint)
    {
        // This doesn't do anything
        CurrentFragmentManager.PopBackStack(_rootFragmentId, 0);

        return true;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Subrato M.'s idea works for me. Here is my C# implementation for Xamarin developers:

```
public class ViewPresenter : MvxAppCompatViewPresenter
{
    private string _rootFragmentName;
    private string _currentFragmentName;

    public ViewPresenter(IEnumerable<Assembly> androidViewAssemblies) : base(androidViewAssemblies)
    {
        AddPresentationHintHandler<SetRootHint>(SetRootHintHandler);
        AddPresentationHintHandler<PopToRootHint>(PopToRootHintHandler);
    }

    protected override void ShowFragment(Type view, MvxFragmentPresentationAttribute attribute, MvxViewModelRequest request)
    {
        base.ShowFragment(view, attribute, request);

        _currentFragmentName = view.FullName;
    }

    private bool SetRootHintHandler(SetRootHint hint)
    {
        _rootFragmentName = _currentFragmentName;

        return true;
    }

    private bool PopToRootHintHandler(PopToRootHint hint)
    {
        while (CurrentFragmentManager.BackStackEntryCount > 0 &&
               CurrentFragmentManager.GetBackStackEntryAt(CurrentFragmentManager.BackStackEntryCount-1).Name.ToLowerInvariant() != _rootFragmentName.ToLowerInvariant())
        {
            CurrentFragmentManager.PopBackStackImmediate();
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call popBackStack from a BackStackChangedListener recursively until you reach your desired Fragment:

```
boolean isBackStackListenerAdded = false;

public void popFragments() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        if(!isBackStackListenerAdded) {
            isBackStackListenerAdded = true;
            getFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(listener);
        }
    }
}

FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener listener = new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onBackStackChanged() {
        String fragmentTag = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() - 1).getName();
        Fragment currentBackStackFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag);
        if(currentBackStackFragment instanceof AFragment) {
            if(isBackStackListenerAdded) {
                getFragmentManager().removeOnBackStackChangedListener(this);
                isBackStackListenerAdded = false;
            }
        } else {
            popFragments();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Does `getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("visible_fragment")` return the current active fragment on top of the stack?

Comment: I have edited the answer a short while ago. Can find the current fragment tag after the pop happened.

Comment: This idea worked for me. I edited my post to include my C# implementation